# google apps script function that gets a certain colomn in spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

Can I create a Google apps script that gets information from a whole Colomn in a apps spreadsheet and do upon it an action?

I've searched the Class spreadsheet link https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_spreadsheet
but i don't know which method I am going to use actually, anyone can help giving me a push? I am new to the Google apps scripts

Comment: removed the appengine tag, as it's relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use the `.getRange()` method to select what cells you want. Then to get all the values, you call `.getValues()`. Example:

```
var vals = sheet.getRange("C2:C").getValues();
```

Now `vals` is a 2 dimensional array that is accessible by `vals[rowNum][colNum]`. If you're grabbing only one column, the `colNum` will always be `0`.